# How do I print all columns in a sqlalchemy query?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Heres my code so far:

```
from db_declarative import Base, OwnershipDocument
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql://iswdp:password@localhost/my_db')

Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker()
DBSession.bind = engine
session = DBSession()

q_all = session.query(tablename).first()
```

From q_all I can print a single value with q_all.columnName.  How do I print all of them?  The simple way seems like it should be something like:

```
for i in q_all:
    print(i)
```

but that just says the object is not iterable.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways, which are a bit different.
You can get this info from `__table__` attribute of a mapped object, for example:

```
In [2]: obj.__table__.columns.keys()
Out[2]: 
['id',
 'email',
 'username',
 'password',
 'active']

In [3]: obj.__table__.columns.values()
Out[3]: 
[Column('id', Integer(), table=<users>, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
 Column('email', String(length=255), table=<users>, nullable=False),
 Column('username', String(length=64), table=<users>, nullable=False),
 Column('password', String(length=128), table=<users>),
 Column('active', Boolean(), table=<users>, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause('0', for_update=False))]
```

You can also just look at the `__dict__` property to see currently loaded attibutes. Note that this will also show attributes that are not columns.

```
In [4]: obj.__dict__
Out[4]: 
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState at 0x7fb04df6b470>,
 'active': True,
 'email': 'test@example.com',
 'id': 3,
 'username': 'test'}
```